# How can i deactivate the CodeIgniter Cache only for a controller?

Tags: caching, codeigniter

Good morning readers,

I have a little problem with caching feature of CI.
When i generate a view with data from database, the data are always the same until il manually delete all cache files.

Is there any way to delete / invalidate the cache ?

I tried to set the cache limit to 1 minute, but i didn't work.

Thanks for incoming answers.

Answer (score 2):

From the CodeIgniter [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html):

> "If you no longer wish to cache a file
>   you can remove the caching tag and it
>   will no longer be refreshed when it
>   expires. Note: Removing the tag will
>   not delete the cache immediately. It
>   will have to expire normally. If you
>   need to remove it earlier you will
>   need to manually delete it from your
>   cache folder."

If you don't want any pages that originate from a specific controller to be cached at all, don't include the

```
$this->output->cache(n);
```

tag in any of its functions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you suuure something in the view changed?
and you have:

```
$this->output->cache(1);
```

in the right function? (anywhere in the function)

The page should be refreshed after a minute.

Did you try clear your browser cache? (ctrl+f5)

Answer (score 0):

Technically from CI documentation cache is enable for each function. So if you have a controller and a method called "uncached" for rxample it should be enoug remove the tag `$this->output->cache(n);` from that method while the users use them.

Remember not add it from the constructor otherwiser unchached will be cached anyways.